# add(ServiceLoad) was called without a registered event handler. Make sure to register a handler via on<ServiceLoad>((event, emit) {...}) Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, webapi

i have this kind of prob, i want integrate Flutter with .Net core web API. I'm new to flutter so, i just followed the tutorial,i`m encounter an runtime error, where in tutorial use depreceated MapEventtoState method emit event

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:testproject_flutter/Service/bloc/bloc.dart';

import '../repository/service_repository.dart';


class ServiceBloc extends Bloc<ServiceEvent, ServiceState> {
  final ServiceRepository serviceRepository;

  ServiceBloc({required this.serviceRepository})
      : super(ServiceLoading());

      

  @override
  on<ServiceBloc>(ServiceEvent handler, Emitter<ServiceState> emit)async* {
    if (handler is ServiceLoad) {
      const Text("Service load method");
      yield ServiceLoading();

      try {
        final services = await serviceRepository.getServices();
        Text("This is the service $services");
        yield ServicesLoadSuccess(services);
      } catch (_) {
        yield ServiceOperationFailure();
      }
    }

    if (handler is ServiceCreate) {
      try {
        await serviceRepository.createService(handler.service);
        final services = await serviceRepository.getServices();
        yield ServicesLoadSuccess(services);
      } catch (_) {
        yield ServiceOperationFailure();
      }
    }

    if (handler is ServiceUpdate) {
      try {
        await serviceRepository.updateService(handler.service);
        final services = await serviceRepository.getServices();
        yield ServicesLoadSuccess(services);
      } catch (_) {
        yield ServiceOperationFailure();
      }
    }

    if (handler is ServiceDelete) {
      try {
        await serviceRepository.deleteService(handler.service.id);
        final services = await serviceRepository.getServices();
        yield ServicesLoadSuccess(services);
      } catch (e) {
        Text("Error de,ete=$e");
        yield ServiceOperationFailure();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the code above is service_bloc.dart. the code still has an error and i dont know to use new event handler, how to solve this

Comment: instead of overriding `ServiceLoading` can you call them on constructor body like `super(ServiceLoading()){ on<ServiceLoad>....}`